# Mac OS X Specify Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: macos, macros, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How can i set the keyboard in Mac OS X Yosemite so i can map the function keys to write specified symbols?

I want to be able to write `\(` every time press `F1`

Comment: this question is best asked on the http://superuser.exchange.com site, because this forum is for coding rather than general hardware or software issues.

Answer (score 1):

use Automator!

Open Automator (search for it in spotlight) and click the new document button

select service as the type of document

on the top left, there is a search bar in Automator. Simply search for run

one of the resulting options is Run AppleScript

Drag this onto the main part of the window, it will add a skeleton script
under where it says (*Your script goes here *), type this:

```
tell application "System Events"
  keystroke "\\("
end tell
```

the two slashes are needed to produce one slash!

Now save this, the default location is fine!

Next, go into settings. open the keyboard icon

under the shortcuts tab, choose in the left pane, Services

Scroll to the bottom and your script should appear! select it and Double click where it says add shortcut. Now input your short cut. make sure there is no other shortcut assigned to that key

Now I must admit, I didn't get f1 to work in some apps because they had override shortcuts for F1. For example, the settings search bar printed ( when I hit F1 but in notes it didn't. If you have a keyboeard, you should probably try an F key greater than 12

Hope this works!

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise how you can write the apple script?

Comment: Yes, I will be, just gonna boot up my mac for you! disclaimer! With my 2008 MacBook, this may take some time!

Comment: thank you, how i can find the keys i need. I want to use also the underscore_ but when i try with KEY::Minus MODIFIER::SHIFT_L  it gives the wrong character. i have a german keyboard.